# reading from input tag outside form element

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, input

I have a web page with an input field (a calendar to select a date from).
The problem is that I need to read that input field from 2 different form elements that each have their own action and other values.

```
|calendar|   [do this]   [do that]
```

I don't want to copy the input field in both forms since it would look silly.
Any suggestions?

Edit: here's the two forms:

```
<form action="/adm/user/credit/update?sms=<?=$id?>&user=<?=$user?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="isPaid" value="1"/>
    <label for="datums">Datums: </label>
    <input type="text" id="datums" name="datums"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Paid" style="background-color:green; color:white"/>
</form>
<form action="/adm/user/credit/extend?sms=<?=$id?>&user=<?=$user?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="<?=$phone?>">
    <select name="period">
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
    </select> days
    <input type="submit" value="Extend" style="background-color: blue; color: white">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give it unique ID and use `document.getElementById` like this anywhere you want:

```
var myValue = document.getElementById("myInputID").value;
```

This way it doesn't matter where the `input` is located, it can even be outiside of any form.

Edit:
To read the value upon submit, first add the `onsubmit` part to the relevant form:

```
<form action="....." onsubmit="ReadValue(this);">
```

And now have this in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ReadValue(oForm) {
   var myValue = document.getElementById("myInputID").value;
   alert("value is: " + myValue);
}
</script>
```

This will show the value as alert dialog.. if you want to populate hidden form field with the value, have such code instead:

```
function ReadValue(oForm) {
   var myValue = document.getElementById("myInputID").value;
   oForm.elements["myHiddenFieldId"].value = myValue;
}
```

Hope it's clear enough! :)

Comment: Unfortunately I know very little about javascript, could you please add a usage example? How do I read that value on submit?

Comment: So I just add a hidden field to both forms and set its value to the value of the outside input field? Like `<input type="hidden" name="datums" value="0" />` and the value gets changed on submitting?

Comment: @jur if you want to send the value of that external input then yes, that's correct. You can also give it same name in both forms it won't cause any conflicts.

Comment: Cheers @jur glad I was able to help.. :)