# Input outside of multiple form containers

Tags: html

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_form.asp

So in the link above, it shows that an `<input>` (select) can be outside of the `<form>` container, as long as the form is reference.

However, what if I have multiple forms and I would like to make sure that the value from `<select>` is included in the form that is submitted. How would I go doing that?

An example:

```
<select id="item1">....</select>
<form id="form1">...</form>
<form id="form2">...</form>
<form id="form3">...</form>
<form id="form4">...</form>
```

I want to make it so that no matter which form is submitted, `item1` is always included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
<select id="item1" name="item1">....</select>
<form id="form1" onsubmit="document.getElementById('h1').value = document.getElementById('item1').value">
<input type=hidden value="" id="h1" name="item1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a javascript onsubmit, such as is provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016996/2593267), may be useful to get the data and append it to your form, regardless of the submitted form.